# Shell Bags Registry - which resolution in use

Tags: windows-registry, resolution, regedit

I've been using windows registries to organize my folders (with a .bat file) every morning, I just change the location and size and open a window and change again and so on and so on, this is the registry I've been changing (one for each side, left, right, top and bottom), this makes my life much easier as with one click I have 8 windows open, each one in the right folder and all of them in the right position when I start working.

```
"HKCU\SOFTWARE\Classes\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Bags\AllFolders\Shell" /v "WinPos3840x2160x96(1).left" /t REG_DWORD /d 0 /f
```

but the thing is, I need to plug my laptop in different screens and because of that, I have different screen resolutions so I always need to check which one is the one to change, I've had several versions

3840x2160x96
1920x1080x96
3840x2160x120
3840x2160x96

I'm looking for a key that tells me the current resolution so I can create something to read that key and depending of the current resolution, it decides which one to change because at the moment, I have 4 different bat and when I go somewhere else, I need to them to see which one works and, sometimes, create a new one.

I've searched all over and I can't find the key!

Comment: What does this have to do with "Shell Bags? I have a PowerShell module that can save and restore Explorer windows to their previous size/position if that's what you're kludging through with registry edits.

Comment: Hi, sorry I'm new here, I saw the title shell bags in another post and it was talking about this and the registry is shell bags so I though it was that, sorry
No, saving position and restoring is not what I'm looking for, what I need is to know the resolution to know which registry I need to change (3840x2160x96, 1920x1080x96, 3840x2160x120, 3840x2160x96...) if there a registry like current version that tells me which one is the right one, it would sort my issue...
Thanks

Comment: You're better off querying the system as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73858737/9406738).`

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that